# How to Make Stripe Checkout Sum Up Values?

Tags: stripe-payments, e-commerce, checkout, shopping-cart, orders

Context: e-commerce Store that sends data to the Admin Dashboard and processes payments via Stripe Checkout. Built with React, Next.js, Prisma DB.

ISSUE: Instead of accounting for the shippingCost and stateTax all that's displayed on Stripe Checkout is the sum of the cost of all individual items added to cart.

WHAT MUST BE DISPLAYED: The sum of the cost of those individual items PLUS shippingCost and stateTax - in other words the grand total. I attached the screenshot to show what goes into it.

If the reason why lies in the line_items than how do I adjust them to display the grand total?

```
  products.forEach((product) => {
line_items.push({
  quantity: 1,
  price_data: {
    currency: 'USD',
    product_data: {
      name: product.name,
    },
    unit_amount: product.price.toNumber() * 100,
  }
});
});

  const order = await prismadb.order.create({
data: {
  storeId: params.storeId,
  isPaid: false,
  orderItems: {
    create: orderItems.productIds.map((productId: string) => ({
      product: {
        connect: {
          id: productId
        }
      },
      shippingType: orderItems.shippingType,
      shippingCost: orderItems.shippingCost.toString(),
      stateTax: orderItems.stateTax.toString(),
    }))
  }
}
});
```

[Cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rbmmm.png)
[Prisma DB relationships and models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxwmJ.png)

Comment: I don't really understand what you're struggling with. Checkout is Stripe's hosted payment page. You control was it being bought via the `line_items` parameter and Stripe will automatically do the calculation, display what's being bought, the total amount, etc. This part seems to work or you'd get an error on creation. Is your question specifically about that Prisma-relationship? If so that's not really a Stripe question so I want to make sure you clarify your exact issue.

Comment: Hi, sorry if it wasn't clear, the issue is instead of accounting for the shippingCost and stateTax all that's displayed in Stripe Checkout is the sum of the cost of all individual items added to cart. While what must be displayed is the sum of the cost of those individual items PLUS shippingCost and stateTax - in other words the grand total. I attached the screenshot before to show what goes into it.

Comment: If the reason why lies in the line_items than how do I adjust them to account not just for the total cost of the individual items but also for the shippingCost and stateTax?
  products.forEach((product) => {
    line_items.push({
      quantity: 1,
      price_data: {
        currency: 'USD',
        product_data: {
          name: product.name,
        },
        unit_amount: product.price.toNumber() * 100,
      }
    });
  });

I hope it makes my question clearer...

Comment: Shipping and tax calculation works differently in Checkout. You likely want to read Stripe's official docs here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/during-payment/charge-shipping?payment-ui=checkout

Comment: That’s not very helpful, as you see I am not using Stripe shipping and tax calculation methods but the custom ones. Besides I wouldn’t have asked this question unless I went over every possible official documentation I could find. Never mind though, already figured out the solution. Thank you.